# How to run maven webapp from eclipse with embedded tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications

I can run a normal dynamic web app from eclipse with embedded tomcat. I found it very convenient for testing and debugging. However, I cannot run a maven webapp from my eclipse with embedded tomcat. I have set the run configurations for the project properly. And after I click run on the "Run Configurations" window, the tomcat server is started successfully. However, my maven web app does not start (the homepage of the app is not displayed on the web browser). Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [M2E Maven Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) provides an integration with the Eclipse WTP Project called [M2E-WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) which provides the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Torsten. I do have the M2E plugin. But I still cannot start the website.